# how to generate dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data with me , which is one dropdown data and one from textbox values which i generate dynamic and get the values.
now i want to generate the table from these value. I get values in alert but I struggling to generate the table

here is my code:

```
$('#save_skills').on("click",function(){
    $('.importance option:selected').each(function(){
        importance = $(this).text();
    })
    $('input.skill ').each(function() {
        skill =  $(this).val();
        alert(skill);
    });
    $('#div_skills').append('<table class="table table-bordered"><tr><td>'+ skill +'</td><td>'+ importance +'</td></tr></table>') 
});
```

I tried this but i get only last record, how to use for loop for below code, I am confused:

```
$('#div_skills').append('<table class="table table-bordered"><tr><td>'+ skill +'</td><td>'+ importance +'</td></tr></table>')
```

i generate this html dynamically:

```
$("#addSkills_link").on("click", function () {

          $("#table_skills").

                append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control skill" id="new_skill" placeholder="Skills"></td><td><select class="form-control importance" id="ddl_skills"><option value="">Select importance</option><option value="">1</option><option value="">2</option><option value="">3</option><option value="">4</option><option value="">5</option><option value="">6</option><option value="">7</option><option value="">8</option><option value="">9</option><option value="">10</option></select></td>');
      });
```

Comment: Please provide a working snippet that shows the exact problem you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join all values like,

```
var importance = [],skill=[];
$('#save_skills').on("click",function(){
    $('.importance option:selected').each(function(){
       importance.push($(this).text());    
    });
    $('input.skill').each(function() {
       skill.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#div_skills').append('<table class="table table-bordered"><tr><td>'+ skill.join(', ') +'</td><td>'+ importance.join(', ') +'</td></tr></table>') 
});
```

**Updated,** after the comment `php | 8 and in second row: java | 9` your code should be like,

```js
$('#save_skills').on("click",function(){
    table = $('<table class="table table-bordered"></table>').appendTo($('#div_skills').empty())
    $('input.skill').each(function(index) {
       skill= $(this).val();
       importance= $('.importance').eq(index).find('option:selected').text();    
       table.append('<tr><td>'+skill+'</td><td>'+importance+'</td></tr>');
   });
});
```

```css
#div_skills{border:1px solid #0cf}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control skill" id="new_skill" placeholder="Skills"></td><td>
<select class="form-control importance" id="ddl_skills"><option value="">Select importance</option><option value="">1</option><option value="">2</option><option value="">3</option><option value="">4</option><option value="">5</option><option value="">6</option><option value="">7</option><option value="">8</option><option value="">9</option><option value="">10</option></select></td></tr>

<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control skill" id="new_skill" placeholder="Skills"></td><td>
<select class="form-control importance" id="ddl_skills"><option value="">Select importance</option><option value="">1</option><option value="">2</option><option value="">3</option><option value="">4</option><option value="">5</option><option value="">6</option><option value="">7</option><option value="">8</option><option value="">9</option><option value="">10</option></select></td></tr>
</table>
<div id="div_skills"></div>
<button id="save_skills">Save Skills</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Rohan, It works, but I want both records as different row.

Comment: For this you need to create 2 rows 1 for Skill And another for Importance like `<tr><td>'+ skill +'</td></tr><tr><td>'+ importance +'</td></tr>`

Comment: I want o/p like this: in first row : php  |  8 and in second row: java | 9 . i.e php having 8 ratings and java have 9 rating. I want display importance in front of skills

Answer (score 0):

Just add your table in your html like so :

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="div_skills_table"></table>
```

And modify your script with this :

```
$('input.skill').each(function() {
    skill =  $(this).val();
    $('#div_skills_table').append('<tr><td>'+ skill +'</td><td>'+ importance +'</td></tr>');
});
```

It will add a new row per skill